# What is the right way to use multiple using statements with possible exception?

Tags: c#, try-catch, sqlconnection, sqlcommand, sqlexception

I'm working with SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommand.

I was just wondering if the following code is correct and what is the better way if possible to do this.

```
private void FillWithData(int id)
{
    try
    { 
       LoadTable1(id);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){throw ex}
}

private void LoadTable1(SqlConnection conn, int id)
{
   try
   {
       using (conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString)) 
       using (SqlDataAdapter table1DA = new SqlDataAdapter ())
       {
          DataTable tblTable1 = Table1;
          SqlCommand table1CMD = getSelectTable1(conn, id);
          table1DA.SelectCommand = table1CMD;
          table1DA.Fill(tblTable1);
          table1CMD.Dispose();
       }
   }
   catch(SqlException ex)
   {
       if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
       conn.Dispose();
       throw ex;   
   }
   finally
   {
       try
       {
          if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception){}
       conn.Dispose();
   }         
}
```

I'm going to have some more methods that do the same for other tables as well. Currently everything is executed under one method that has `try/catch` block inside of which `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommands` for each table are defined. My goal is to separate logic for different tables into different methods

Comment: You are now closing `conn` three times. One is enough, just leave it to the `using(){}` and remove all that catch and finally clutter.

Comment: And don't bother with a parameter if you're immediately going to overwrite its value... (the `conn` parameter here)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't do `throw ex;` inside a catch block - this destroys the call stack information inside the exception. Instead just do `throw;`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few possible improvements:

1. Do not swallow exceptions (`catch (Exception){}`) - either handle it or just let it bubble up.
2. You do not need to close or dispose of the connection - the `using` block will do that for you
3. You should put the `SqlCommand` in a `using` block as well.
4. You are passed in a connection but then overwrite the *local* variable - the connection that is passed in is not changed.  Why have a parameter at all?
5. `throw ex;` is not a best practice since you lose the original stack trace - better to just `throw;` instead.  Since you aren't *doing* anything in the catch block except closing the connection (which is unnecessary) the catch block can be removed altogether.

Making those changes would leave you with just:

```
private void FillWithData(int id)
{
    LoadTable1(id);
}
private void LoadTable1(int id)
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString)) 
   using (SqlDataAdapter table1DA = new SqlDataAdapter ())
   using (SqlCommand table1CMD = getSelectTable1(conn, id))
   {
      DataTable tblTable1 = Table1;
      table1DA.SelectCommand = table1CMD;
      table1DA.Fill(tblTable1);
   }
}
```

And since `SqlDataAdapter` has a constructor that takes a `SQlCommand` you can just do:

```
private void LoadTable1(int id)
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString)) 
   using (SqlCommand table1CMD = getSelectTable1(conn, id))
   using (SqlDataAdapter table1DA = new SqlDataAdapter (table1CMD))
   {
      table1DA.Fill(Table1);
   }
}
```

Comment: What about if I have exceptions? How should I handle those with this construct?

Comment: @gene - Your exception handling is useless. The "using" statements ensure that Dispose() is called on your objects (even in the case an exception is thrown) and the implementation of Dispose() on connections automatically closes the connection if it's open. Everything in your catch and finally blocks is just noise that serves no purpose.

Comment: So, basically, when using "using" clause, catching exception is not necessary, since it will dispose the object anyway in case of exception?

Comment: @gene Exactly.  That's the point of a `using` statement - it disposes of the object in a `finally` block so you don't have to.  The only reason you would catch an exception is if you wanted to _do something_ about it, which you don't in your case.

Comment: What if I want to do something, like displaying the messages or some other things, how then should I take care of this

Comment: If the code inside the `using` throws an exception, it will bubble up, so you would treat it just like any other code (put it inside a `try` and add a `catch` block); you just don't need to add any disposal code.